# Stacks and Queues in order to test a palindrome

Tags: c++, linked-list, palindrome

I have made a custom Stack and Queue class. In my program I want to use them both to test out if a word or phrase is a Palindrome. However, I need to change in my Stack and Queue class, which will allow both numbers and strings. How would I go about this in a simple manner? I read up on people having trouble using Palindromes but that is with the  and  C++ reference class. Any ideas? Here is my code which works with numbers.

```
//Queue.h

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Queue
{
public:
    Queue();
    ~Queue();
    void enqueue(int);
    int dequeue();
    void print();
private:
    typedef struct Node {
        Node *link_;
        int item_;
    } NODE;
    NODE* head_;
};

Queue::Queue()
{
    head_ = NULL;
}

Queue::~Queue()
{
    if (head_ == NULL) return;
    NODE *cur = head_;
    while (cur) {
        Node *ptr = cur;
        cur = cur->link_;
        delete ptr;
    }
}

void Queue::enqueue(int n)
{
    if (head_ == NULL) {
        head_ = new NODE;
        head_->item_ = n;
        head_->link_ = NULL;
        return;
    }
    NODE *cur = head_;
    while (cur) {
        if (cur->link_ == NULL) {
            NODE *ptr = new NODE;
            ptr->item_ = n;
            ptr->link_ = NULL;
            cur->link_ = ptr;
            return;
        }
        cur = cur->link_;
    }
}

void Queue::print()
{
    if (head_ == NULL) return;
    Node *cur = head_;
    cout << "This is your current queue: " << endl;
    while (cur) {
        cout << cur->item_ << " ";
        cur = cur->link_;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int Queue::dequeue()
{
    if (head_ == NULL) {
        cout << "This is an empty queue!!" << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    NODE *tmp = head_;
    int value = head_->item_;
    if (head_->link_) {
        head_ = head_->link_;
    }
    // pop the last element (head)
    else {
        delete tmp;
        head_ = NULL;
    }
    cout << "You dequeued: " << value << endl;;
    return value;
}

int getQueue()
{
    Queue *que = new Queue();
    que->enqueue(15);
    que->enqueue(75);
    que->enqueue(105);
    que->enqueue(25);
    que->enqueue(55);
    que->print();
    que->dequeue(); que->print();
    que->dequeue(); que->print();
    que->dequeue(); que->print();
    que->dequeue(); que->print();
    que->dequeue(); que->print();
    que->dequeue(); que->print();
    return 0;
}
```

I am really new into coding for C++ and really want to learn. If anyone could help me out it'll be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused. Is your question about finding palindromes, or is it about implementing a stack/queue to store a string?

Comment: I stated in the question that I need help trying a way to change it to allow both integers and strings

Comment: Ah, okay. Can you store a string as a list of characters (ie: a C-style string)? If that's acceptable, you'd just need to change a few "int"s to "char"s.

Comment: Are you trying to allow both integers and strings in the same queue?  Or are you trying to design a queue so that it could be used as an integer queue or a string queue?

Comment: @DrewDormann preferably both, so that the user could either do strings or numbers in the palindrome

Comment: @Cooper that particular design is possible but it has a lot of tricky edge cases.  If each element in your queue might be an int or might be a string, you'll discover that none of your code can do string things or int things to all the elements, as they may be the wrong kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to make your Queue type templated

```
template <typename T> class Queue
{
public:
    Queue();
    ~Queue();
    void enqueue(const T &value);
    T dequeue();
    void print();
private:
    typedef struct Node {
        Node *link_;
        T item_;
    } NODE;
    NODE* head_;
};
```

Now you can use it as

```
Queue<int> intQueue;
intQueue.enqueue(1);
intQueue.enqueue(2);
int i = intQueue.dequeue();

Queue<string> stringQueue;
stringQueue.enqueue("hello");

Queue<char>  charQueue;
charQueue.enqueue('c');
```